# How do I join 3 tables in asp.net? 1st table is related to the 2nd only. 3rd is related to 2nd only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, web-applications

I have a problem. I want to join 3 tables in my asp.net web app but I am unsure on how to do that. Could you please help me?

I want to join StudioId to a Movie table. However, Movie is not related in any way to Studio table. Movie is related to Movie_Producers (being a bridge table), Movie_Producers table is related to Producers and Producers are related to Studio. How can I somehow join Studio to Movie, considering previousely mentioned relations?

Here is my current index controller (I have tried to add Studio by "ThenInclude" - it does not work since I cannot pass Studio model to my Movie View):

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var applicationDbContext = _context.Movie
            .Include(m => m.Cinema)
            .Include(m => m.Movie_Producers)
            .ThenInclude(mp => mp.Producer)
                .ThenInclude(mp => mp.Studio);
            return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
        }
```

here is my Movie model:

```
public class Movie
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        //Cinema
        public Cinema? Cinema { get; set; }

        public int CinemaId { get; set; }

        //Producer
        public List<Movie_Producer>? Movie_Producers { get; set; }

    }
```

here is my Movie_Producers model:

```
    public class Movie_Producer
    {    
        public int Id { get; set; }

        //Relationships
        public Movie? Movie { get; set; }

        public int MovieId { get; set; }

        //producer
        public Producer? Producer { get; set; }

        public int ProducerId { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my Producers model:

```
    public class Producer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Profile Picture is required")]
        public string ProfilePictureURL { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Full Name is required")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Full Name must be between 3 and 50 chars")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Biography")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Biography is required")]
        public string Bio { get; set; }

        //Relationships

        //movie_producer
        public List<Movie_Producer>? Movie_Producers { get; set; }

        //studio

        public Studio? Studio { get; set; }

        public int StudioId { get; set; }
}
```

and finally Studio model:

```
 public class Studio
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Studio_Name { get; set; }

        public string Owner { get; set; }

        //Relationships
        public List<Producer>? Producers { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried joining through linq but I am unsure on how to do that since it is necessary to provide a new view model.

On other hand, when I create a new view model I am unsure on how to create relationships allowing me to showcase related data in the view.

The final goal is to link Movies with Studio, not directly, but through Movie_Producers or through Producers. Is this even possible? Thank you!

Comment: use join table via linq A to B & C and when you select it use Anonymous method like -> new ViewModelname { ViewModeld = x.Id, ViewModelItem2 = x.Name} .  I think all should be Inner join . Look for join in Linq google it . Should be fairly simple

Comment: If you can please give me a picture view of your table structure. i can join it. I cant seem to understand the wording above sorry ;)) . Also try joining the table in SQL . LINQ is a representation of your SQL query. Anything you can do in SQL you can pretty much do via LINQ.

Comment: just a note to comply with the EF standard, replaced 
'public List<Movie_Producer>? Movie_Producers { get; set; } ' by `public virtual ICollection<Movie_Producers> Movie_Producers { get; } = new List<Movie_Producers>;
and 'public Studio? Studio { get; set; }' by 'public virtual Studio? Studio { get; set; }' and if you can replace the naming of the Movie_Producer class with MovieProducer
another thing you forgot the Cinema class. Note puts you just the relevant stuff

Comment: hey @user3920526 not trying to be rude or anything but I am not sure how to post photo here. Please check relationships through models, they can be easily observed there :)

Comment: @Laaziv thank you for your reply. Could you please tell me why do you want me to change these names? What is an EF standard? Is it entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ queries to join the tables and retrieve the desired data.

```
var result = context.Table1
    .Join(context.Table2,
        t1 => t1.Table2Id,
        t2 => t2.Id,
        (t1, t2) => new { T1 = t1, T2 = t2 })
    .Join(context.Table3,
        t => t.T2.Id,
        t3 => t3.Table2Id,
        (t, t3) => new { T1 = t.T1, T2 = t.T2, T3 = t3 })
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Table1Data = x.T1,
        Table2Data = x.T2,
        Table3Data = x.T3
    })
    .ToList();
```

may help :)

Comment: Looks like it could help. Where do I use it though? In my controller?

Comment: @md317 If you have any repository, you can do it there or anywhere that has access to your DbContext. If your controller can see DbContext, use it there, but I suggest not doing this in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

your code is right, but you had done the relationships wrong, adds virtual modifier and uses ICollection. Here is an example:

```cs
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CinemaId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CinemaId))]public Cinema? Cinema { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movie_Producer> Movie_Producers { get; } = new List<Movie_Producer>();
}
public class MovieConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Movie>
{
    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Movie>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Movie> builder)
    {

    }
}
public class Cinema
{
    [Key]public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class CinemaConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Cinema>
{
    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Cinema>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Cinema> builder)
    {
                
    }
}
public class Movie_Producer
{
    [Key]public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(MovieId))] public virtual Movie? Movie { get; set; }
    public int ProducerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProducerId))] public virtual Producer? Producer { get; set; }
}
public class Movie_ProducerConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Movie_Producer>
{
    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Movie_Producer>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Movie_Producer> builder)
    {

    }
}
public class Producer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int StudioId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(StudioId))] public virtual Studio? Studio { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movie_Producer> Movie_Producers { get; } = new List<Movie_Producer>();
}
public class ProducerConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Producer>
{
    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Producer>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Producer> builder)
    {

    }
}
public class Studio
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<Producer> Producers { get; } = new List<Producer>();
}
public class StudioConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Studio>
{
    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Studio>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Studio> builder)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, Could you explain WHY my relationships are wrong? All of the tables in my database are related properly. Foreign Keys are in right places. Everything seems fine. Isn't this approach outdated:  [ForeignKey(nameof(CinemaId))]public Cinema? Cinema { get; set; } ?

Comment: @MD317 replaces public `List<Movie_Producer>?` with `public virtual ICollection<Movie_Producer> Movie_Producers { get; } = new List()<Movie_Producer>;`
 for `[ForeignKey(nameof(StudioId))]` you proof the deleted me personally I leave it none I rename a property by a name that does not follow the convention.
I tested your code is it works just added virtual modifier and replace List with ICollection